# R regressão em dados da mesma linha

Tags: r, regressão, lapply

Tenho os seguintes dados:

```
mes <- c("jan","fev","mar","abr","maio","jun","ago","set","out")
a <- c(32.3,32.7,32.6,33.1,33.0,33.5,33.4,33.4,34.9)
b <- c(19.2,19.2,19.6,19.7,19.7,19.9,20.0,20.0,20.4)
c <- c(14.7,15.0,15.6,16.2,16.4,17.0,17.7,18.3,19.1)
d <- c(24.2,24.3,24.7,25.0,25.5,26.4,26.7,27.1,27.6) 
temp <- data.frame(mes,a,b,c,d)
y <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
```

gostaria de aplicar uma regressão `lm(log(mes) ~ y)`

mas nas linhas, e usando uma função `lapply()`, ou alo do tipo, para aplicar em todas as linhas.
um jeito que encontrei de exemplificar foi este:

```
lm(log(temp[1,])~y)
lm(log(temp[2,])~y)
lm(log(temp[3,])~y)
lm(log(temp[4,])~y)
```

não sei se é possível.

a base de dados que eu tenho é extensa, se for possível fazer isso, como eu faria para rodar os dados, linha por linha, salvando os coeficientes da regressão e o R2 ajustado do modelo?

Pensei em criar uma lista, mas não sei bem como fazer, se puderem me dar pelo menos um norte, ficarei grato.

Comment: `lm(log(mes) ~ y)` vai dar erro, nem sequer tentei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é assim tão difícil como isso. Na solução abaixo

1. Calculo o logaritmo de cada coluna exceto a primeira logo no início.
2. Aplico (`apply`) o modelo `lm(x ~ y)` a cada linha.
3. E depois há várias instruções para extrair os vários valores que se podem querer, tais como os coeficientes beta, os p-valores, o coeficiente de determinação.

O código é mesmo muito simples, trata-se de aplicações sucessivas de `*apply`.

```
log_temp <- apply(temp[-1], 2, log)

model_list <- apply(log_temp, 1, function(x) lm(x ~ y))

coef_list <- t(sapply(model_list, coef))

model_smry <- lapply(model_list, summary)

R2_list <- sapply(model_smry, '[[', 'r.squared')
pval_list <- t(sapply(model_smry, function(LM){
  LM[['coefficients']][, 4]
}))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @RuiBarradas, você tem umas dicas onde estudar e aprofundar os conhecimentos em r?

Comment: Há imensos documentos na página oficial do R, [The R Project for Statistical Computing](https://www.r-project.org/). Também se podem encontrar muitos outros na net. Ou em livrarias. Por exemplo a coleção da [Springer](https://www.springer.com/series/6991) entre muitas outras.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível ajustar o modelo de regressão da forma que vc quer, pois não faz sentido.
Se vc ajustar um modelo para cada linha da base, vc terá uma amostra de tamanho 1, e com isso, vc não terá variabilidade nos dados para calcular os erros padrões dos estimadores/variância do modelo.

Eu sugiro a leitura de algum livro do tipo Análise de Regressão Linear no R (tem vários), para que então você continue a modelar os dados.

Ainda, "y" deveria estar no mesmo `data.frame` para melhor organização do banco de dados.

Comment: Na verdade, o AP pode fazer a regressão que deseja. Descontada a coluna do mês, cada linha do data frame `temp` possui 4 observações, que é o mesmo número de elementos em `y`.

Comment: @guilherme, entendo, porém é como o @MarcusNunes afimou. Acho que não me expressei bem na pergunta. O meu banco de dados tem mais observações, eu simplifiquei para a,b,c,d, e `y` com 4 observações também. @MarcusNunes o que seria AP?

Comment: AP = Autor da Pergunta

Comment: Beleza! No momento, eu havia lido no ônibus, e nunca tinha me deparado com essa entrada de dados, por isso pensei que não seria possível. Mas conforme o código do Rui, e dada a forma que os dados entram, cada linha da base funciona como que o "vetor tradicional", sendo "y" minha covariável. Entendi. Irei reconstruir minha resposta no futuro de uma maneira que penso ser mais lógica.. Obrigado!!